# Reactjs Drawer not opening on every page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation-drawer, drawer, react-context

I have a navbar as a header on each page and the navbar has a button for a drawer but the drawer only opens when the onClick function is added to each page like below. How do I make the drawer open wherever the navbar is without duplicating the same code?

```
class ProductPage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    shoppingCartOpen: false,
  };
  drawerToggleClickHandler = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return { shoppingCartOpen: !prevState.shoppingCartOpen };
    });
  };

  render() {
    let shoppingCartDrawer;
    if (this.state.shoppingCartOpen) {
      shoppingCartDrawer = <ShoppingCartDrawer />;
    }
    return (
      <ProductStyling>
        <ButtonAppBar drawerClickHandler={this.drawerToggleClickHandler} />
        {shoppingCartDrawer}
```

I add the navbar to app.js so it appears on every page but I can't get the drawer `onclick` event to work

Comment: move the state into a constructor